import torch throws TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'torch._C.DisableTorchFunctionSubclass'
I installed torch==1.13.0+cu116 and ran Python on the terminal. Then, I did import torch, but I got the following error:
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/work/temp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 231, in <module>
    obj.__module__ = 'torch'
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'torch._C.DisableTorchFunctionSubclass'

I'm using Python 3.8.10, nvcc release 11.6, and driver version 535.104.05
But the following command not show an error message
pip install torch==2.3.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121`

Why is this error occurring?
